# How to replace multiple numbers in a data frame on R?

Tags: r

I'm new to R. How do I change multiple numbers in a data frame? I've created a data frame from an csv file, and I want to be able to replace all the numbers in one column with different numbers while making sure I am still using a data frame. I tried replacing "30" with "9999", and "28" with "2800".

[image]

I tried using the code below but the RHELP2 became a "character" instead of a data frame which isn't what I wanted. Thanks.

EDIT: proofreading

```
RHELP2 <- RHELP$score %>% 
              replace(RHELP$summary_score == 30, "9999") %>%
              replace(RHELP$summary_score == 28, "2800")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
RHELP2 <- RHELP 

RHELP2$score[RHELP2$score == 30] <- 9999
RHELP2$score[RHELP2$score == 28] <- 2800
```

---

Another option if you want to use pipes and `replace`

```
library(dplyr)

RHELP2 %>%
  mutate(score = replace(score, score == 30, 9999), 
         score = replace(score, score == 28, 2800))
```